# Как запретить выделение Item по нажатию правой кнопки мыши при вызове ContextMenu?

Tags: c#, wpf

Пример кода:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Folders}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedFolder}">
                    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Grid>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                                <Grid.ContextMenu>
                                    <ContextMenu>
                                        <MenuItem Header="{Binding Name}"/>
                                        <Separator/>
                                        <MenuItem Header="Удалить"/>
                                    </ContextMenu>
                                </Grid.ContextMenu>
                            </Grid>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                </ListBox>
```

При вызове меню по правой кнопке, одновременно срабатывает Selected объекта где вызывается меню.

Comment: Наводящий вопрос: Вы контекст меню хотите у всего ListBox установить? Или у каждого элемента отдельно?

Comment: Да, уже понял свою ошибку. Вообще по замыслу при вызове меню в итеме не должен срабатывать выделение(Select). Сейчас поправлю вопрос и изменю пример кода.

Comment: Вызов контекст меню не вызывает выбор элемента.

Comment: Изменил вопрос и уточнил какое текущие поведение.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3010703/how-can-i-prevent-listbox-from-selecting-an-item-when-i-right-click-it

Comment: John спасибо, оказалось все на столько легко. А то до этого и тригеры и что только не пробовал )))

Comment: Просто научитесь пользоваться английским поиском (составлять запросы на английском). В русском сегменте искать зачастую бесполезно, а в английском на все типичные вопросы ответы уже даны. Этот ответ первый в выдаче гугла на запрос "listbox context menu wpf".

Comment: @John [Пожалуйста, не отправляйте задающих вопросы в поисковики](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2013/179763)

Comment: @tym32167 я довольно часто гуглю англоязычный SO, чтобы дать тут ответ, например

Comment: @AntonShakalo, но это не значит, что нужно отправлять в гугл спрашивающего

Comment: @AntonShakalo тут даже были ответы - чисто переводы с EnSO, ничего плохого в этом не вижу

Comment: @АндрейNOP конечно же, раз мы можем помочь